# Text Searching and Manipulation

Tags: c#, replace, listbox, text-manipulation

So the file I am importing into a `ListBox` looks like this *(each **newline** is a new item in the `ListBox`)*:

```
C2  CAP-00128G 238.385 205.944 0  0402_8   
C1  CAP-00128G 236.260 204.844 0  0402_8   //Same as above 1 (C2)
C18 CAP-00129G 230.960 190.619 0  0402_4   
C19 CAP-00129G 248.060 195.344 0  0402_4
C63 CAP-00129G 231.535 203.844 0  0402_4
C65 CAP-00129G 232.260 195.419 0  0402_4   //Same as above 3 (C18, C19, C63)
C71 CAP-00130G 240.151 195.123 0  0402_4   //1 Occurrence
C4  CAP-00151G 247.435 202.019 90 0402_3   //1 Occurrence
L1  IND-00007G 248.110 205.719 0  0402_4   //1 Occurrence
R30 RES-00455G 273.010 184.644 0  0402_8
R9  RES-00455G 236.260 203.794 0  0402_8
R29 RES-00455G 272.960 174.694 0  0402_8   //Same as above 2 (R30, R9)
```

I am looking at each item in the `ListBox` and grabbing the **2nd column** values and seeing how many times they occur ***(see the numbers after the text - ie, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3 when looking down the columns)*** and outputting it to a .txt file. Here is what it looks like (this is the first part of the .txt file the second part will be listed below).

```
( 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "CAP-00128G" "" 2 0 0 0 0 0 )   // 2 = C2, C1
( 2 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "CAP-00129G" "" 4 0 0 0 0 0 )   // 4 = C18, C19, C63, C65
( 3 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "CAP-00130G" "" 1 0 0 0 0 0 )   // 1 = C71
( 4 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "CAP-00151G" "" 1 0 0 0 0 0 )   // 1 = C4
( 5 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "IND-00007G" "" 1 0 0 0 0 0 )   // 1 = L1
( 6 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "RES-00455G" "" 3 0 0 0 0 0 )   // 3 = R30, R9, R29
```

Using this code for the above text:

```
List<string> partList = new List<string>();

// Builds original list first.
foreach (var item in placementOneListBox.Items)   //This is getting all the lines in the ListBox and storing them in a List<string>.
{
    // Creates a string of the items in the ListBox. 
    var newItems = item.ToString();

    // Replaces any multiple spaces (tabs) with a single space. 
    newItems = Regex.Replace(newItems, @"\s+", " ");

    // Splits each line by spaces. 
    var eachItem = newItems.Split(' ');

    // Add each item to the List.
    partList.Add(eachItem[1]);
}

Dictionary<string, int> result = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var item in partList)
{
    if (result.ContainsKey(item))
        result[item]++;
    else
        result.Add(item, 1);
}

foreach (var item in result)
{
    sw.WriteLine("( " + deviceCount + " 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 \"\" \"" + item.Key + "\" \"\" " + item.Value + " 0 0 0 0 0 )");

    deviceCount++;
}
```

Using the same `ListBox` I am printing out the second half of the .txt file. The second part of the text file looks like this:

```
( 1 1 "DD" 1 238.385 205.944 0 1 2 0 0 "C2" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 2 1 "DD" 1 236.260 204.844 0 1 2 0 0 "C1" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 3 1 "DD" 1 230.960 190.619 0 1 2 0 0 "C18" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 4 1 "DD" 1 248.060 195.344 0 1 2 0 0 "C19" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 5 1 "DD" 1 231.535 203.844 0 1 2 0 0 "C63" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 6 1 "DD" 1 232.260 195.419 0 1 2 0 0 "C65" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 7 1 "DD" 1 240.151 195.123 0 1 2 0 0 "C71" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 8 1 "DD" 1 247.435 202.019 90 1 2 0 0 "C4" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 9 1 "DD" 1 248.110 205.719 0 1 2 0 0 "L1" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 10 1 "DD" 1 273.010 184.644 0 1 2 0 0 "R30" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 11 1 "DD" 1 236.260 203.794 0 1 2 0 0 "R9" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 12 1 "DD" 1 272.960 174.694 0 1 2 0 0 "R29" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
```

Using the code:

```
foreach (var item in placementOneListBox.Items)
{
    var newItems = item.ToString();
    newItems = Regex.Replace(newItems, @"\s+", " ");

    var eachItem = newItems.Split(' ');

    sw.WriteLine("( " + lineCount + " 0 \"FD\" 1 " + eachItem[2] + " " + eachItem[3]
                      + " 0 0 0 0 0 \"" + eachItem[0] + "\" \"\" \"\" \"\" \"\" 0 0 0 "
                      + lineCount + " 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 \"\" )");
    lineCount++;
}

sw.WriteLine(")");
sw.WriteLine(")");

sw.Close();
```

### SO my problem is:

The second part of the file is being printed out properly except I need to replace the *value* that happens after **"DD"** in the second part of the file with the ***1st (number) column*** in the first part of the file.. So *instead* of the ***2nd part*** of the file being printed out how it is, I would like to have it printed out different depending on if it matched the values. This is what I would like to have the file look like:

```
( 1 1 "DD" 1 238.385 205.944 0 1 2 0 0 "C2" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 2 1 "DD" 1 236.260 204.844 0 1 2 0 0 "C1" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 3 1 "DD" 2 230.960 190.619 0 1 2 0 0 "C18" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 4 1 "DD" 2 248.060 195.344 0 1 2 0 0 "C19" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 5 1 "DD" 2 231.535 203.844 0 1 2 0 0 "C63" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 6 1 "DD" 2 232.260 195.419 0 1 2 0 0 "C65" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 7 1 "DD" 3 240.151 195.123 0 1 2 0 0 "C71" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 8 1 "DD" 4 247.435 202.019 90 1 2 0 0 "C4" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 9 1 "DD" 5 248.110 205.719 0 1 2 0 0 "L1" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 10 1 "DD" 6 273.010 184.644 0 1 2 0 0 "R30" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 11 1 "DD" 6 236.260 203.794 0 1 2 0 0 "R9" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 12 1 "DD" 6 272.960 174.694 0 1 2 0 0 "R29" "" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
```

- Can anyone help me figure this problem out?

### ***EDIT:***

[Here is the Error I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Kne.png)

Comment: +1 for a detailed question where the concept can carry over to other questions.

Comment: Please don't categorize your question by placing things like "C# - " in your subject line. We use tags for that purpose on [SO].

Comment: It all looks good, but check my code again for the `lookup` declaration that I omitted (which is funny since it's pretty much the cincher for my solution).  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved tersely and relatively easily (or not) using LINQ:

```
// Using the input file:
const string str = "C2  CAP-00128G 238.385 205.944 0  0402_8\n"
                    + "C1  CAP-00128G 236.260 204.844 0  0402_8   #Same as above 1 (C2)\n"
                    + "C18 CAP-00129G 230.960 190.619 0  0402_4   \n"
                    + "C19 CAP-00129G 248.060 195.344 0  0402_4\n"
                    + "C63 CAP-00129G 231.535 203.844 0  0402_4\n"
                    + "C65 CAP-00129G 232.260 195.419 0  0402_4   #Same as above 3 (C18, C19, C63)\n"
                    + "C71 CAP-00130G 240.151 195.123 0  0402_4   #1 Occurrence\n"
                    + "C4  CAP-00151G 247.435 202.019 90 0402_3   #1 Occurrence\n"
                    + "L1  IND-00007G 248.110 205.719 0  0402_4   #1 Occurrence\n"
                    + "R30 RES-00455G 273.010 184.644 0  0402_8\n"
                    + "R9  RES-00455G 236.260 203.794 0  0402_8\n"
                    + "R29 RES-00455G 272.960 174.694 0  0402_8   #Same as above 2 (R30, R9)\n";

// And the reader (notice that by using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` 
// you don't need your regular expression to normalize spacing):

var listLines = new List<string[]>();
using (var tr = new StringReader(str))
{
    string l;
    while ((l = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
        listLines.Add(l.Split(new[] {' '}, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}

// this is a cool trick when you need to build up a dictionary.  The problem 
// with using a dictionary in a case like this is that, unless you have some
// multidictionary implementation, you are going to be stuck with a lot of 
// extra code that maintains the value collection (you know what I mean... the
// List<string[]> part of Dictionary<string, List<string[]>>.

var lookup = (from line in listLines group line by line[1]).ToArray();

// Part 1 -- The Select allows me to run a lambda function.  In this case, 
// I use a variation that provides me with a counter.  Nothing really special 
// here.

var part1 = lookup.Select(
    (x, i) =>
    string.Format(@"( {0} 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 """" ""{1}"" """" {2} 0 0 0 0 0 )", 
        i + 1, x.Key, x.Count()));

// And Part 2 - A little trickier.  I'm using SelectMany to flatten my dictionary
// back out, but while doing so, I use an anonymous type to effectively decorate
// each line with the index of the group it belongs to.  From then on it is again
// just a standard call to string.Format (which, if you aren't using it, please do.
// It's a lot more readable than string concatenations).

var part2 = lookup.SelectMany((x,i) => x.Select(y => new { Index = i, Item = y }))
    .Select((x,i) => string.Format(
       @"( {0} 1 ""DD"" {1} {2} {3} {4} 1 2 0 0 ""{5}"" """" """" """" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 """" )", 
       i + 1, x.Index + 1, x.Item[2], x.Item[3], x.Item[4], x.Item[0] ));


// And so you can see your results in the console:

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", part1));
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", part2));
```

Finally, the output is:

```
( 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "CAP-00128G" "" 2 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 2 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "CAP-00129G" "" 4 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 3 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "CAP-00130G" "" 1 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 4 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "CAP-00151G" "" 1 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 5 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "IND-00007G" "" 1 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 6 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "RES-00455G" "" 3 0 0 0 0 0 )

( 1 1 "DD" 1 238.385 205.944 0 1 2 0 0 "C2" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 2 1 "DD" 1 236.260 204.844 0 1 2 0 0 "C1" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 3 1 "DD" 2 230.960 190.619 0 1 2 0 0 "C18" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 4 1 "DD" 2 248.060 195.344 0 1 2 0 0 "C19" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 5 1 "DD" 2 231.535 203.844 0 1 2 0 0 "C63" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 6 1 "DD" 2 232.260 195.419 0 1 2 0 0 "C65" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 7 1 "DD" 3 240.151 195.123 0 1 2 0 0 "C71" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 8 1 "DD" 4 247.435 202.019 90 1 2 0 0 "C4" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 9 1 "DD" 5 248.110 205.719 0 1 2 0 0 "L1" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 10 1 "DD" 6 273.010 184.644 0 1 2 0 0 "R30" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 11 1 "DD" 6 236.260 203.794 0 1 2 0 0 "R9" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
( 12 1 "DD" 6 272.960 174.694 0 1 2 0 0 "R29" "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" )
```

Which I think is exactly what you are after.

So... hopefully there are some fun new things here to get familiar with:

- LINQ (This may change your life)
- Lambda functions
- Anonymous Types
- SelectMany (with indexer)
- String.Format

-- UPDATE --

If, as was mentioned in the quotes, you are getting the items from a listbox, you can initialize `listlines` as shown here:

```
var listLines = from l in ListBox.Items
      select l.ToString().Split(new[] {' '}, 
         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You no longer need the StringReader at all.  Now, you might have to play with ToString() to make sure each item really is a string, as I'm not exactly sure what type the collection actually is.

Comment: I am trying to work with what you wrote and I cannot seem to get it to work properly. First, ***lookup*** does not exist as an action I can use. I posted an "EDIT" section above showing your code worked into what I already had -- do you see anything that looks like it will not work properly? I am also wondering if you could explain what is going on in your code a little bit.. I am unfamilair with LINQ

Comment: Whoops... I left a line out.  Correcting it now.

Comment: I modified the listing so you can just cut and paste the whole thing.

Comment: Check again... I cut and paste this into an empty project and it gave me grief with my Join extension function.  I replaced it with the string.Join and it runs again.

Comment: I may have to edit out the part where it says "relatively easily"  :-D

Comment: That works much better! It works great with the `const string str`. How can I get it to work to create that text from a `ListBox`... I was trying to do it this way: `foreach (var item in ListBox.Items) { partList.Add(item + "\n"); }`.. but that does not seem to be working for me.. and with that I changed your `using (var tr = new StringReader(str))` to `using (var tr = new StringReader(partList.ToString())) `

Comment: I updated my answer to help you out.  If you feel this answer is correct, please mark it as such.  :-)  Thank you, this was fun.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This answer is great and I appreciate you helping me through and writing decriptions of what is all going on. Sorry to be such a hassle but the *Update* above does not seem to work properly! Ill post the link above for the error

Comment: @theNoobGuy let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2390/discussion-between-michael-hays-and-thenoobguy)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a delimited file.

If you load this text file in to a `DataTable`, you can query and output it as you wish by using a number of features which `DataTable` offers like custom views and querying with `Select` method.

You can also loop through all the rows in a table easily to perform whatever substitutions you need.

So the idea is to load the file in to a table, manipulate the table as needed, and render table's content to text for output.